# How do I get the right selector to style this image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to style the image here:

```
<div id="site-title">
<a href="http://**.com/" rel="home">
<img src="http://**.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/transparent-logo.png" alt="" width="369" height="66">
</a>
<a class="home" href="http://**.com/" rel="home"></a>
</div>
```

I tried to use the selector

```
#site-title a img {
}
```

But that doesn't seem to be accessing the image. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Which styles are you adding, selector seems fine

Comment: Your selector is fine: http://jsfiddle.net/hn8Eu/1/

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
#site-title img { /* Your styles here*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

**The id Selector**

The id selector is used to specify a style for a single, unique element.

The id selector uses the id attribute of the HTML element, and is defined with a "#".

The style rule below will be applied to the element with id="InHereWeAreUsingId":

http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_id.asp

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp

HTML

```
<div id="InHereWeAreUsingId">In Here We are using a Id to Identify this div </div>
```

CSS

```
#InHereWeAreUsingId
{
text-align:center;
color:red;
```

}

**So In your question**

HTML

```
<div id="site-title">
<a href="http://**.com/" rel="home">
<img src="http://**.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/transparent-logo.png" alt="" width="369" height="66">
</a>
<a class="home" href="http://**.com/" rel="home"></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#site-title > img{




}
```

Comment: No, this won't work. `img` is not a direct descendant of `#site-title`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may have modified your question to fix a typo that the previous answers brought up.

```
#site-title a img {}
```

If you have your selector formatted in that way it should work.